# Suppose that the function $f:(-1,1) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has n derivatives.

Tags: derivatives, proof-explanation, solution-verification

Suppose that the function $f:(-1,1) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has n derivatives. Assume that there is an $M>0$ such that $|f(x)| \leq M|x|^n$ for all $x\in (-1,1)$. Prove that $ f(0) = f'(0) = ... = f^{(n-1)}(0) = 0$ where n is a natural number

My attempt at the proof follows.

We are given that $|f(x)| \leq M|x|^n$ for all x on the interval $(-1,1)$. Since f is differentiable by defintion, it follows that $f(x)$ is continuous on (-1,1). Therefore if we let $ x = 0$, it follows that $|f(0)| \leq M|0|^n = 0$ and therefore it follows that $f(0) = 0$. Since $f$ has n derivatives it follows that $f'(0) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)- f(0)}{x}$ and therefore $|f'(0)| = \lim_{x \to 0} |\frac{f(x)- f(0)}{x}| = \lim_{x \to 0} |\frac{f(x)}{x}| \leq \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{M|x|^n}{|x|} = \lim_{x \to 0} M|x|^{n-1} = 0$.

Similarly, $f''(0) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f'(x) - f'(0)}{x}$. This is where I get stuck. If we take the absolute value of $f''$ it would follow that $|f''(0)| = \lim_{x \to 0} |\frac{f'(x)}{x}|$. Ideally, I want to be able to get f(x) in the numerator so we can use the given inequality, but I am not sure how to do this. I was wondering if this proof is on the right track, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**: My answer is correct now. Sorry for the inconvenience.

We have that $|f(x)|\le M|x|^n$. We want to prove $f^{(k)}(0)=0$ for every $0\le k\le n-1$.

The case $k=0$ is trivial. Now we'll use strong induction, so suppose we have the result up to some $k$ such that $0\le k\le n-2$. Then $f^{(l)}(0)=0$ for every $0\le l\le k$. Since $f\in C^n\big((-1,1)\big)$ and $k\le n-2$, for every $x\in(-1,1)$ we can consider the Maclaurin series (Taylor series at $x=0$) of degree $k+1$ and express the remainder as $\dfrac{f^{(k+2)}(\xi_x)}{(k+2)!}x^{k+2}$ with $\xi_x$ strictly between $0$ and $x$.

Then, for $x\in(-1,1)$,

$f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)x+\dfrac{f''(0)}{2!}x^2+\ldots+\dfrac{f^{(k+1)}(0)}{(k+1)!}x^{k+1}+\dfrac{f^{(k+2)}(\xi_x)}{(k+2)!}x^{k+2}$.

Remember we have $f^{(l)}(0)=0$ for every $0\le l\le k$ by induction hypothesis, so

$f(x)=\dfrac{f^{(k+1)}(0)}{(k+1)!}x^{k+1}+\dfrac{f^{(k+2)}(\xi_x)}{(k+2)!}x^{k+2}$, from what we get

$f^{(k+1)}(0)=(k+1)!\dfrac{f(x)}{x^{k+1}}-\dfrac{f^{(k+2)}(\xi_x)}{k+2}x$

Now, since $f\in C^n\big((-1,1)\big)$ and $k+2\le n$, and taking $x\to0$ provoques $\xi_x\to0$, we have that

$f^{(k+2)}(\xi_x)\xrightarrow{x\to0}f^{(k+2)}(0)$.

Also remember that we had $|f(x)|\le M|x|^n\Rightarrow \dfrac{|f(x)|}{|x|^{k+1}}\le M|x|^{n-k-1}$ (and $n-k-1\ge1$).

Finally, $\left|f^{(k+1)}(0)\right|\le(k+1)!\dfrac{|f(x)|}{|x|^{k+1}}+\dfrac{\left|f^{(k+2)}(\xi_x)\right|}{k+2}|x|\le (k+1)!M|x|^{n-k-1}+\dfrac{\left|f^{(k+2)}(\xi_x)\right|}{k+2}|x|\xrightarrow{x\to0}0$

We get that $f^{(k+1)}(0)=0$, so we conclude it is true for every $0\le k\le n-1$ (note we can't extend this to $k=n$, since we needed the remainder of the Taylor series, which would be with $f^{(n+1)}$ in that case).

Comment: very nice, thank you

Comment: I corrected the answer. Sorry for the inconvenience.